# MongoDB Text Index using Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

Using the MongoDB Java API, I have not been able to successfully locate a full example using text search. The code I am using is this:

```
DBCollection coll;
String searchString = "Test String";

coll.createIndex(new BasicDBObject ("blogcomments", "text"));
DBObject q = start("blogcomments").text(searchString).get();
```

The name of my collection that I am performing the search on is blogcomments. `creatIndex()` is the replacement method for the deprecated method `ensureIndex()`. I have seen examples for how to use the `createIndex()`, but not how to execute actual searches with the Java API. Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite right.  Queries that use indexes of type "text" can not specify a field name at query time.  Instead, the field names to include in the index are specified at index creation time.  See [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) for examples. Your query will look like this:

```
DBObject q = QueryBuilder.start().text(searchString).get();
```